# basic javascript to advanced javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code for a content scroller. This has been implemented with basic jquery. Iam trying to convert the same using advanced javascript concepts. Guide me to implement the same.

Working Code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var currentPosition = 0,
    slideWidth = 112,
    slides = $('#scroller ul li'),
    numberOfSlides = slides.length;
    scrollerContainer = $('#scroller ul');

$(scrollerContainer).css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);

manageControls(currentPosition);

$('.control').click(function(){
    currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id')=='rightControl') ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;
    manageControls(currentPosition);
    $(scrollerContainer).animate({
        'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-(currentPosition*3))
    });
});

function manageControls(position){
    if(position==0){ $('#leftControl').hide() }
    else{ $('#leftControl').show() }

    if((position*3)==numberOfSlides-1 || (position*3)==numberOfSlides-3 || (position*3)==numberOfSlides-2) { $('#rightControl').hide() }
    else{ $('#rightControl').show() }
}
});
```

Advanced Code Structure : Initial understanding

```
if(!scroller) { var scroller = {}; }

scroller =  
{
    videos : {

        moveThumbnails : function() {

        },
        gotonextThumbnails : function() {
            var obj = this;

        },
        gotopreviousThumbnails : function() {
            var obj = this;

        },
        init : function() {
            var obj = this;

        }
    },
    init : function() {
        var obj = this;
        this.videos.init();
    }
}
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/9EyEu/

Comment: I don't intend to troll, but do you have a definition of what's _advanced_ and what's not in JavaScript?

Comment: @Tharabas at a beginner level, we used to write javascript where we marely use Object communication. Advanced javascript concpets like modular javascript so that later on same code can be converted to plugin easily. Just trying yo get my hands dirty with how object communicates and how we can achieve optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't post a full answer about the "advanced JavaScript" part of your question, but here's what I would change in the actual code:

- **Use `jQuery.fn.find` method**

  You could optimize this `$('#scroller ul li')` with this `$('#scroller').find('ul li')`. When using a selector like `#someidname`, jQuery can use directly the native method `document.getElementById`. When using  `#someidname something`, then jQuery has to parse the selector, and only after this it can say "oh there's an id string in there !".
- **Don't recreate jQuery objects**

  When doing `var scrollerContainer = $('#scroller ul');`,  `scrollerContainer` becomes a jQuery object. Then, you **don't need** to do `$(scrollerContainer).someMethodName()` but you could directly write `scrollerContainer.someMethodName()`.
- **Always use triple equals sign**

  You should (almost) always prefer `===` over `==`. The double equal sign may have some unexpected behavior such as `"\t \n" == 0` which evaluate to `true`.
- **Don't use jQuery when it's not needed**

  `$(this).attr('id')` could be simplified in `this.id`. This way, you don't construct a new jQuery object (this can be costly when done in loops for example), and the `id` property is supported in a cross-browser way so you don't have to worry about it.
- **Cache your DOM selections**

  `$('#leftControl')` and `$('#rightControl')` should be cached in variables in the same way as `$('#scroller ul')` is. We should avoid doing the same DOM query wherever it's possible.
- **Prefer `jQuery.fn.on` or `jQuery.fn.bind` methods over traditional ones**

  Because:

  - they are **faster**: internally `$('whatever').click(fn)` calls `$('whatever').on('click', fn)`, so you can use it directly and avoid a function call,
  - they are **more flexible**: you can bind the same function to *different events* (`$('whatever').on('click mouseenter mouseleave', fn)`), you can *namespace your events* (`$('whatever').on('click.myPlugin', fn)`) which IMO would be useful in your case (your doing some sort of namespacing)
- **Simplify (Math) expressions**

  IMO, the code `slideWidth*(-(currentPosition*3))` is not really readable. Why using such parenthesis ? And what about this inner `-` sign ?

  What about writing it this way `-slideWidth*currentPosition*3` ?

  Also, the part `(position*3)==numberOfSlides-1 || (position*3)==numberOfSlides-3 || (position*3)==numberOfSlides-2` can be simplified. Have a look (shorter variable names for the example):

  ```
  (p*3)==n-1 || (p*3)==n-3 || (p*3)==n-2
  // which is equivalent to
  1==n-p*3 || 3==n-p*3 || 2==n-p*3
  // which is equivalent to
  1 <= n-p*3 && n-p*3 <= 3
  // and also equivalent to
  (n-p*3-1) in [0,0,0]
  ```

  so you end up with this:

  ```
  if( (numberOfSlides-position*3-1) in [0,0,0] ) {
      ...
  }
  ```

  That `(n-p*3-1) in [0,0,0]` part is quite interesting. When doing `a in b` you'll search if the array `b` has the index `a`. This only happens in our case because `b` **is** an array. So we use a array `b = [0,0,0]` which has 3 elements. **3** comes from the expression `n-p*3`, this is the maximum X of the three `n-p*X` forms seen above. Then, since `[0,0,0]` has 3 elements, its index are 0, 1, and 2. So the test if the expression `n-p*3` equals to one of 1, 2, or 3, we have to subtract `-1`.

  To explain it on another way, we can say that `0 in [0,0,0]`, `1 in [0,0,0]`, and `2 in [0,0,0]` will both be true (because we're using the array indexes and not its values), and all others numerical values will evaluate the expression to `false`. Since what you want you is to check if `n-p*3` is of one 1, 2 or 3, if we remove 1 to this expression, we retrieve our values 0, 1, and 2 from above which will evaluate the expression to `true`.

  If you think this one is too tricky (and to be honest, it is !), you can do the following, which avoid code repetition and where **the intent is explicit and readable** (I would recommend this technique over the `index i [0,0,0]` one which is implicit and less readable IMO)

  ```
  var temp = numberOfSlides - position * 3;
  if( 1 <= temp && temp <= 3 ) {
      ...
  }
  ```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Nice in on array of index trick.

Comment: The `in [0,0,0]` "trick" is terribly unreadable. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I'd support @RoToRa here. The _trick_ will trick yourself after not having read that line of code for a while. Better extract the value and compare it in a more readable fashion like `var v = numberOfSlides - position * 3 - 1; if (v >= 0 && v <= 2) ...` as @pomeh recommended the line before the _trick_.

Comment: @RoToRa you're right. This is the kind of "high level" optimization, or the "art" to use JavaScript's leakiness to achieve a unexpected behavior. While I'm agree with you that this not readable and unclear (I've updated the answer to point it out), this **could** be the kind of trick used in "high level" optimization or "high level" of code compression, but that may represent a very low percentage or real-world applications ;) Anyway, I think this kind of JavaScript trick is funny, and that's why I've included it, but I would say **don't use it unless you really know what're doing** :)

Comment: Maybe add use function binding instead of `var that = this`, etc? +1 for using `.on()` instead of `.click()`.

Comment: @Cobby how would you write the function binding here ?

Comment: I'd probably use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/), it has `_.bind()` and my personal favourite `_.bindAll()`.